# pip install is not installing executables in /usr/local/bin

Tags: apt, python, pip

I recently setup a new Ubuntu 16.04.2 machine. I'm trying to install some python packages, but all the packages are getting installed at `/usr/local/lib/python2.7.10/bin` instead of `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`.

```
Installing collected packages: git-review

  changing mode of /usr/local/lib/python2.7.10/bin/git-review to 755
Successfully installed git-review-1.25.0
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: Does running `git review` work?

Comment: No, I had to manually invoke it from `/usr/local/lib/python2.7.10/bin/git-review`.

Comment: `/usr/bin` shouldn't be used because it's used only for dpkg/Apt packages. Does `pip install --install-option="--prefix=/usr/local/bin" git-review` put it in `/usr/local/bin` and have it working correctly?

Comment: Nope. It still goes at the same location.

Comment: OK, I found a slightly-different option that works here. Try my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to remove the `pip` package that was installed by `apt`.

```
sudo apt remove python-pip
```

And then install pip again according to instructions on their website - https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/.

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
```

Looks like `pip` from Ubuntu's default repository is not same as one distributed by pypi.

Comment: You can do the last part without a temporary file with `sudo python <(wget -O- https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py 2>/dev/null)`

Comment: OMG! Jesus christ ubuntu

Answer (score 11):

Open a terminal and run:

```
pip uninstall git-review
sudo pip uninstall git-review
sudo pip install --prefix /usr/local git-review
git review --version
```

The last command should output something like `git-review version 1.25.0`.

Comment: That did work, but now I'm getting another error. `$ git review
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/git-review", line 7, in <module>
    from git_review.cmd import main
ImportError: No module named git_review.cmd`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing that, so I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Actually I removed the installed pip using `sudo apt remove python-pip` and then reinstalled pip according to instructions here - https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: Its use is cautioned there: `Be cautious if you're using a Python install that's managed by your operating system or another package manager. get-pip.py does not coordinate with those tools, and may leave your system in an inconsistent state.`

Comment: Yes exactly @chai-t-rex.